# Nested ajax calls inside a loop are not executing in order

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise, jquery-deferred

I have a nested AJAX call.

**AJAX bit:**

```
function a(val){
    var def = $.Deferred();
    return $.ajax({
        type : "get",
        url : "myservlet",
        beforeSend : function() {
            $('#text1').css({
                "color" : "red"
            });
            $('#text1').text("Running Graph");
        },
        data : {
            "boxval" : val
        }
    }).done(function(responseText) {
        $('#text1').css({
            "color" : "green"
        });
        $('#text1').text(responseText);
    }).then(function(){
        return $.when(b());
    });
}

function b(){
    return $.ajax({
        type : "get",
        url : "ConnectServlet",
        beforeSend : function() {
            $('#text2').css({
                "color" : "red"
            });
            $('#text2').text("Copying Files and preparing pSet");
        }
    }).done(function(responseText) {
        $('#text2').css({
            "color" : "green"
        });
        $('#text2').text(responseText); 
    }).then(function(){
        return $.when(c());
    });
}

function c(){
    return $.ajax({
        type : "get",
        url : "CopyServlet",
        beforeSend : function() {
            $('#text3').css({
                "color" : "red"
            });
            $('#text3').text("Running Dynamic Diff Graph");
        }
    }).done(function(responseText) {
        $('#text3').css({
            "color" : "green"
        });
        $('#text3').text(responseText);
    }).then(function(){
        return $.when(d());
    });
}

function d(){
    $('#summary').show();
}
```

What I require is the entire chain of the ajax call( the main ajax call, function b, function c and function d) to be executed in order for every iteration of the loop.

What is happening instead is that the entire main ajax call is getting executed without calling function b for every iteration of the loop.

I need it do the following:

- a
- b
- c
- d
- a
- b
- c
- d
- ...

What is happening instead is:

- a
- a
- a
- ...
- b

How do get this fixed?

Answer (score 1):

each call takes a while to execute and you haven't accounted for that at all.

you fire the first GET request and that can take seconds to return. Your JavaScript doesn't wait for that to happen and keeps executing code.

A solution would be to introduce something like a "javascript promise". You basically only call function b once the first call has actually completed and you have the response data.

Here's an article to get you started : https://davidwalsh.name/promises

Don't stop here though and read some more on the subject. You can chain multiple things like this and have the behaviour as you need it.